# Unable to mimic request in scrapy

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests, scrapy

I am trying to implement a request being sent after clicking on continue button from this [website](https://cdplusmobile.marioncountyfl.org/pdswebservices/PROD/webpermitnew/webpermits.dll) but the response is always some xml code instead of html.

```
def start_requests(self):
    codes = range(2022010002,2022010003)
    for code in codes:
        fd = {'EDTPERMITNBR': f'{code}',
         'BTNGUESTLOGIN': '',
         'IW_FormName': 'FrmMain',
         'IW_FormClass': 'TFrmMain',
         'IW_width': '652',
         'IW_height': '797',
         'IW_Action': 'BTNGUESTLOGIN',
         'IW_ActionParam': '',
         'IW_Offset': '',
         'IW_SessionID_': 'S1uxlkMRpiOnzXriVlSIoBbAqJS',
         'IW_TrackID_': '10',
         'IW_WindowID_': 'I1',
         'IW_AjaxID': str(time.time())[:15].replace('.','')}

        url = 'https://cdplusmobile.marioncountyfl.org/pdswebservices/PROD/webpermitnew/webpermits.dll/S1uxlkMRpiOnzXriVlSIoBbAqJS/$/callback?callback=BTNGUESTLOGIN.DoOnAsyncClick&x=138&y=32&which=0&modifiers='
        yield scrapy.FormRequest(url,method='post',formdata=fd,headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/113.0'})
```

Answer (score -2):

Please bear in mind that web scraping is an intricate task with potential legal and ethical complexities. It's imperative to abide by the terms of use of the website you're scrapping and ensure your actions are in line with applicable laws and regulations.

You seem to be encountering a situation where you're receiving XML instead of HTML. This could occur if the server sends XML as a response format or if you're dealing with an AJAX endpoint, which is typically designed to return XML, JSON, or another data format, rather than a complete HTML page.

Unlike HTML, Scrapy does not inherently manage XML responses. For XML, you'll need to parse it employing libraries such as lxml or BeautifulSoup.

Here's a method to achieve this within your Scrapy spider:

```
from scrapy.http import TextResponse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def parse(self, response):
    # assuming response.body is a blob of XML
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.body, 'lxml') # 'lxml' is the parser for xml
    # Now you can find tags, navigate, or extract info from your xml
    # Suppose we want to find the tag 'your_tag' and extract its text
    your_tag = soup.find('your_tag')
    if your_tag:
        your_info = your_tag.text
        print(your_info)
```

Ensure 'your_tag' is replaced with the actual XML tag you're interested in.

However, if you're anticipating HTML rather than XML, it's possible that the server decides the response format based on the request headers. You could try appending 'Accept': 'text/html' to your headers to show that you'd prefer an HTML response:

```
yield scrapy.FormRequest(url, method='post', formdata=fd, headers={
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/113.0',
    'Accept': 'text/html'
})
```

Finally, it's worth noting that the 'IW_SessionID_' in your form data appears to be a session ID, which likely changes every time a session is started on the server. If that's the case, you will need to find a way to dynamically get the session ID for each new session. This might involve sending a GET request to the page first, parsing the session ID out of the response, and then using that session ID in your POST request.

It's essential to highlight that the 'IW_SessionID_' in your form data seems to be a session ID, which probably changes each time a new session is initiated on the server. If this is true, you'll need to devise a method to dynamically obtain the session ID for every new session. This could involve issuing a GET request to the page first, extracting the session ID from the response, and then using that session ID in your POST request.

It's also worth noting that it appears you're scraping a website that uses Intraweb. Intraweb is an AJAX-based web application development framework. Due to its dynamic, on-the-fly generated requests, it can be more challenging to scrape and may necessitate more advanced scraping methods or tools capable of executing JavaScript, such as Selenium or Pyppeteer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am aware about dynamic nature of the website and formdata variables. My main aim to ask this question was to know if there is any way to scrape such site using Scrapy

Comment: Moreover, parsing of xml content isn't the issue.Basically, the real response page which have the data is in html format

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, 
daniya shyanne!

All eight of your answers here since you joined 3 days ago appear likely to be entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). Please be aware that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. 

We do hope you'll stick around and be a valuable part of our community by posting *your own* quality content. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.